# Power analysis via simulations in Stata version 15.1

Tags: stata, simulate

I have been trying to run this simulation code in Stata version 15.1, but am having issues running it as indicated below.

```
local num_clus 3 6 9 18 36
local clussize 5 10 15 20 25
*Model specifications
local intercept 17.87
local timecoeff1 -5.42
local timecoeff2 -5.72
local timecoeff3 -7.03
local timecoeff4 -6.13
local timecoeff5 -9.13
local intrvcoeff 5.00
local sigma_u3 25.77
local sigma_u2 120.62
local sigma_error 38.35
local nrep 1000
local alpha 0.05

*Generate multi-level data
capture program drop swcrt
program define swcrt, rclass
version 15.1
preserve
clear
args num_clus clussize intercept intrvcoeff timecoeff1 timecoeff2 timecoeff3 timecoeff4 timecoeff5 sigma_u3 sigma_error alpha
assert `num_clus' > 0 & `clussize' > 0 & `intercept' > 0 & `intrvcoeff' > 0 & `timecoeff1' < 0 & `timecoeff2' < 0 & `timecoeff3' < 0 & `timecoeff4' < 0 & `timecoeff5' < 0 & `sigma_u3' > 0 & `sigma_error' > 0 & `alpha' > 0
/*Generate simulated multi—level data*/
qui
clear
set obs `num_clus'
qui gen cluster = _n
qui gen group = 1+mod(_n-1,4)
/*Generate cluster-level errors*/
qui gen u_3 = rnormal(0,`sigma_u3')
expand `clussize'
bysort cluster: gen individual = _n
/*Set up time*/
expand 6
bysort cluster individual: gen time = _n-1
/*Set up intervention variable*/
gen intrv = (time>=group)
/*Generate residual errors*/
qui gen error = rnormal(0,`sigma_error')
/*Generate outcome y*/
qui gen y = `intercept' + `intrvcoeff'*intrv + `timecoeff1'*1.time + `timecoeff2'*2.time + `timecoeff3'*3.time + `timecoeff4'*4.time + `timecoeff5'*5.time + u_3 + error

/*Fit multi-level model to simulated dataset*/
mixed y intrv i.time ||cluster:, covariance(unstructured) reml dfmethod(kroger)

/*Return estimated effect size, bias, p-value, and significance dichotomy*/
tempname M
matrix `M' = r(table)
return scalar bias = _b[intrv] - `intrvcoeff'
return scalar p = `M'[1,4]
return scalar p_= (`M'[1,4] < `alpha')
exit
end swcrt

*Postfile to store results
tempname step
tempfile powerresults
capture postutil clear
postfile `step' num_clus [B]clussize[/B] intrvcoeff p p_ bias using `powerresults', replace
ERROR: (note: file /var/folders/v4/j5kzzhc52q9fvh6w9pcx9fgm0000gn/T//S_00310.00000c not found)

*Loop over number of clusters
foreach c of local num_clus{
display as text "Number of clusters" as result "`c'"
foreach s of local clussize{
display as text "Cluster size" as result "`s'"
forvalue i = 1/`nrep'{
display as text "Iterations" as result `nrep'
quietly swcrt `num_clus' `clussize' `intercept' `intrvcoeff' `timecoeff1' `timecoeff2' `timecoeff3' `timecoeff4' `timecoeff5' `sigma_u3' `sigma_error' `alpha'
post `step' (`c') (`s') (`intrvcoeff') (`r(p)') (`r(p_)') (`r(bias)')
}

}

}
postclose `step'

ERROR: 
Number of clusters3
Cluster size5
Iterations1000
r(9);

*Open results, calculate power
use `powerresults', clear

levelsof num_clus, local(num_clus)
levelsof clussize, local(clussize)
matrix drop _all
*Loop over combinations of clusters
*Add power results to matrix
foreach c of local num_clus{
 foreach s of local clussize{
quietly ci proportions p_ if num_clus == `c' & clussize = `s'
local power `r(proportion)'
local power_lb `r(lb)'
local power_ub `r(ub)'
quietly ci mean bias if num_clus == `c' & clussize = `s'
local bias `r(mean)'
matrix M = nullmat(M) \ (`c', `s', `intrvcoeff', `power', `power_lb', `power_ub', `bias')
 }
}

*Display the matrix
matrix colnames M = c s intrvcoeff power power_lb power_ub bias 
ERROR:
matrix M not found
r(111);
matrix list M, noheader format(%3.2f)
ERROR:
matrix M not found
r(111);
```

There are a few things that seem to be amiss above.

1. I get a message after the postfile command saying that the file is not found. Nowhere in my code do I actually use that name so it seems to be generated by Stata.
2. After the loop and the post command I get error r(9).
3. Error message r(111) - says that the matrix is not found.

I have checked the following parts of the code to try and resolve the issue:

- Specified local macros outside of the program and passed into it via the args statement of the program
- Match between the variables in the call of the swcrt with the args statement in the program
- Match between arguments in assert statement of the program with args command and whether the alligator clips are specified appropriately
- Match b/w the number of variables in the post and postfile commands

I am not quite sure why I get these errors considering that the code did work previously and the program iterated (even when I take away the changes there is still the error). Does anyone know why this happens? If I had to guess, the matrix can't be found because of the error with the file not being found when I use postfile.

Comment: This is a tough call as compared with the ideal MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would be foolish to say that it can't be answered, so I won't, but it would benefit from slimming down.

Comment: Thank your feedback Nick. I listed the errors that popped up, but I am not sure that I could slim the code down any further without making the example non-reproducible. It seems to me that all of it is essential for re-creating those problems. Was there something specific that you had in mind that I could streamline?

Comment: No suggestions from me. My point, unfortunately, is that the whole program is too complicated even to tempt experienced programmers to try to understand what is important. I'd try role reversal in this way: consider what time you are expecting people to give to your question and then whether you expect that they can find a bug in that time.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your suggestions. Would it be possible then if I generated the results (i.e. power conditional on number of clusters and cluster size) in a separate software and create power curves in Stata with them? Effectively that would mean I have a matrix of results that I could create manually.

Comment: Sorry again. I have no experience or insight on this topic.